# C++ Block code saves memory before function finish?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

Since I got more experience with Java and i'm diving now into C++ world, there is something that I know in Java that I dont have sure if it works like on C++.

Actually I got this pseudo C++ code:

```
unsigned long __stdcall MyFunction()
   {
    //Do some code that will take a while to complete...

       {
            MY_BIG_STRUCT mbStruct = {};
            mbStruct.a = "a";
            [...];
            UseMyStructData(&mbStruct);
        }

    //Do some code that will take a while to complete...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So my question is: On JAVA using those code blocks inside brackets `{}` will mark as "free" those variables to GC free them, even if the function didnt finish it's execution. So, on C++ this works in the same way? Or is useless using `{}` if I dont have a block statement (like if, while, switch, etc...)?

Best regards,

Afonso Lage.

Comment: How can it possible work "the same way" -- C++ has a completely different object and memory model from Java. That question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Walter Why? I have a working callback function which uses it on VS2012...

Comment: @Walter - __stdcall is a Windows-specific thing.  It defines whether the called or the calling function cleans up the stack.

Comment: @Walter it's **not** illegal. It's perfectly compliant with the standard. Even in the naming, which specifically reserves anything beginning with double underscores for the particular implementation. Please don't spread FUD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no GC in non-managed C++.  The destructor for mbStruct will be called at the end of the `}` bracket, however because it is a variable on the stack (as opposed to on the heap with `new`).
The `{`  `}` creates a scoping that causes the destructor to be invoked at the closing scoping bracket.  The destructor is guaranteed to run even if an exception is thrown out of the function.

Also, C++ employs 'deterministic destruction' which means you are guaranteed that the destructor will be run synchronously (at the closing `}`), as opposed to a system with a GC where the object is disposed of at the discretion of the GC memory manager.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic variables allocated on stack will be deallocated. This is not the same as garbage collector in Java, since its automatic stack allocation, not heap allocation. Usage-wise it will look the same to you though.

If you allocate something from the heap (using `new`/`malloc`) - you have to de-allocate yourself (using `delete`/`free`). Use [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no GC in C++. However, garbage collectors only deal with memory allocated dynamically. That is with `new` or `malloc()`. Automatic variables are destroyed when their scope exits. `mbStruct` is an automatic variable, so it will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Also, you don't need explicit `{ }` scopes, unless you want fine grained control. Also note that a scope ends even before a closing `}`. For example:

```
void foo()
{
    SomeClass someObj;
    if (some_condition) {
        return;
    }
}
```

`someObj` is going to be destroyed even if `some_condition` is true and the `return` is executed; leaving a scope has the same effect as ending it.

You should take care not to keep pointers (or references) to variables that have gone out of scope. For example, this will blow up:

```
void foo()
{
    SomeClass* someObj_ptr;

    {
        SomeClass someObj;
        someObj_ptr = &someObj;
    }
    someObj_ptr->function(); // Mistake: someObj no longer exists.
}
```

After the inner scope ends, `someObj` has been destroyed but `someObj_ptr` still refers to it. Calling `function()` on it (assuming `SomeClass` has such a member function) is an error. The compiler isn't able to catch that error, mind you. You have to be aware of this and never keep pointers or references to variables that have gone out of scope. Contrary to Java, in C++ variables are not reference counted and are not kept alive if there are references to them. If a variable goes out of scope, it's gone, regardless of whether other variables still refer to them.

Answer (score 0):

Works the same way in C++. Your `MY_BIG_STRUCT` will be released at the end of the block.